# Exhaustive groupBy for enum keys

Tags: kotlin, collections, enums, grouping

I would like to group a list to a Map that contains every single key of an enum class. Consider the following example:

```
enum class E { A, B, C }

fun main() {
    val l = listOf("Alice", "Anne", "Charlie")
    val a = l.groupBy { E.valueOf(it.substring(0,1)) }
    println(a)
}
```

As it is, groupBy returns `{A=[Alice, Anne], C=[Charlie]}`.

I would like it to return `{A=[Alice, Anne], B=[], C=[Charlie]}`.

I know I can create a function that iterates over all the entries of an enum and filters the list that way, thus creating what I want, but that's a very brute-force approach. Is there an existing function that does what I'm after, or a neat and concise way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One strategy would be to create a map of empty defaults and then fill it in using `groupBy`.

```
val a2: Map<E, List<String>> = E.entries.associateWith { emptyList<String>() } + 
    l.groupBy { E.valueOf(it.substring(0,1)) }

val a3: Map<Char, List<String>> = a2.mapKeys { (key, _) -> key.name.first() }
```

This is using `valueOf` and I'm not sure of the time complexity of how it's implemented in the JVM so it may or may not be considered brute force itself. I suppose you could ensure it's not by creating a map first.

```
val entriesByName = E.entries.associateBy(E::name)

val a2: Map<E, List<String>> = E.entries.associateWith { emptyList<String>() } +
        l.groupBy { entriesByName.getValue(it.substring(0,1)) }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
enum class TestEnum { A, B, C }

val list = listOf("Alice", "Anne", "Charlie")

val groupedNames = list.groupBy { it.first() }

val groups = TestEnum.values()
  .map { it.name.first() }
  .associateWith { groupedNames[it] ?: emptyList() }

println(groups)   // Output: {A=[Alice, Anne], B=[], C=[Charlie]}
```

Comment: This looks good, thanks. By the way, since Kotlin 1.9 we can use the more efficient `.entries` instead of `.values()`.

Comment: Just pointing out, this is the exact brute force approach you described in the question, except it's a concise syntax for doing so. It's `O(n * m)`. But actually I don't know if `valueOf` itself is implemented as `O(1)` or `O(n)` in the JVM. If it's implemented as `O(1)`, then you could do this more efficiently in `O(n + m)` time by using `E.entries.associateWith { emptyList<String>() } + l.groupBy { E.valueOf(it.substring(0,1)) }`

Comment: @Tenfour04 You are of course right. Edited the code.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I think you should post your code in the comment above also as an answer.

Comment: One more thing to point out, in the code above, the value of `B` is a `null` rather than an empty list. Not sure which is the OP's desired result. Edit: never mind you just changed that.

Comment: I just noticed it myself and changed it a minute ago.

Comment: Thanks, the newly edited version is much better. By the way, I'm after a `Map<TestEnum, List<String>>` - not a `Map<Char, List<String>>` - so you can leave out the `.map { it.name.first() }` line.